# /etc/resolv.conf gets auto updated by protonvpn?

Tags: resolv.conf, resolvconf

Since I have installed **protonvpn** the `reslov.conf` file **always gets overwritten or sets back to** `::1`.

I always have to manually edit the file before I can access the internet. It doesn´t matter what I set in the network configs in the GUI of my system.

When I start protonvpn the file gets updated to someting like `10.x.x.x` which is probably protons dns server. But before this works I have to change the file manually so that proton can access the internet.

Does the `resolv.conf` has precedence over the graphical settings?
How can I stop this? Or modify it so that the file only gets updated when I actually start protonvpn?

thanks

Comment: AFAIK protonvpn has an option for that - if that's the case, disable it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay the problem was the killswitch feature. I had to disable it with:

```
nmcli connection show --active
```

then picking the right connection and deleting it

```
nmcli connection delete [connection name]
```

here is the detailed instruction: [killswitch disable](https://protonvpn.com/support/official-linux-vpn-debian/)

Comment: you saved my day